# how to find the radius of convergence ? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{x^n}{n} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1})$

Tags: summation

How can i find the radius of convergence ? i dont know where to start i cant use $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ test here.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{x^n}{n} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1})$

the question looks simple but i dont know how to solve it
i got that $R = 0$ but its wrong  because when $x=1$ it is convergent

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the partial sums.

\begin{align}
s_N &= \sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{x^n}n - \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)\\
&= \left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3}\right) + \left(\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4}\right) + \text{ ... } + \left(\frac{x^{N}}{N} - \frac{x^{N+1}}{N+1}\right)\\
&= x - \frac{x^{N+1}}{N+1} 
\end{align}

To evaluate the sum, we take the limit $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}s_N$ and find that the limit is equal to $x$ if $|x|\leq1$ and does not exist otherwise.

This means that the radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is harder, but you can use the ratio test by combining the two fractions under the same denominator.

The $n$th term is equal to: $$\frac{x^n(n+1) - x^{n+1}(n)}{n(n+1)}.$$

Now, for:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{x^{n+1}(n+2) - x^{n+2}(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)} \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{x^n(n+1) - x^{n+1}(n)} \right) < 1$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{x^{n+1}(n+2) - x^{n+2}(n+1)}{x^n(n+1) - x^{n+1}(n)} \cdot \frac{n}{n+1} \cdot \frac{n+1}{n+2} \right)<1$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x^{n+1} - x^{n+2}}{x^n - x^{n+1}} \cdot 1 \cdot 1 <1$$
$$\Rightarrow |x| <1 \ (*)$$

Therefore, the radius of convergence is $1$.

$(*)$: Going back to the original expression $\frac{x^n}{n} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$.